# Making function for checking is file name exist in external storage

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have two Activities .

1.TestActivity : It show list of test document , when user clicks on a button will download the doc.

2.`ShowDownloadedActivity`: It shows list of downloaded files (list of file in external storage ).

In the `TestRecyclerAdapter` I need a method to check whether file already downloaded (in other word is file exist in external storage ?) or not ? if its already downloaded it has to show different text for user (some thing like "downloaded" ).

For achieve this I want to check whether the filename exists in the list of files ("External storage ").

This is the `onCreate` of ShowDownloadedActivity :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_downloaded_file);

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/my.package.name/files/downloaded".toString();

        File file = new File(path);
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        if(file.listFiles() != null){
            for(int i=0; i<list.length ; i++){

                ModelShowFile modelShowFile = new ModelShowFile();
                modelShowFile.setTitle(list[i].getName());

                mylist.add(modelShowFile);
            }

            recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_ac_show_downloaded_file);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ShowDownloadedFileActivity.this));

            adapter = new AdapterRecyclerShowFile(ShowDownloadedFileActivity.this,mylist);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(ShowDownloadedFileActivity.this , "Nothing yet !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Edit :

Guys I need one method in ShowDownloadedActivity with filename as string parameter to check , i.e file with passed fileName is already exists in external storage or not ? that's it .

Thanks :

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing? and are you sure you want to use this line as is: "String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/my.package.name/files/downloaded".toString();" check android docs for more info on it

Comment: Your question not Clear. Please explain more

Comment: @яσѕρєяK I update the question

Comment: Have you tried implementing that or Just asking us to do it for you ??

Comment: @jankigadhiya , ummmmm no i tried .  i just want help !

Comment: Show us what you have tried we will surely help if you are facing any difficulty..!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this it may be help to you

```
 public boolean checkDownload(String filenameWithExtension)
 {
    File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File myFile = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + filenameWithExtension);
    return myFile.exists();
 }
```